# Как можно исправить обеспечение целостности данных?

Tags: ms-access

У меня есть несколько таблиц и вот такая схема.
[image: схема данных]

Я внёс данные во все таблицы, кроме штатного расписания. При добавлении данных в штатное расписание, выдаёт ошибку о нарушение целостности данных и необходимости наличия связанной записи в таблицы "Отделы". Не могу понять чего не хватает. Ниже данные из табл. отделы(все данные вымысел).
[image: Таблица отделы]
А это то, что пытаюсь внести в штатное расписание.
[image: Таблица штатное расписание]

Comment: 1. Проверьте, что типы данных совпадают. Т.е., например, код отдела в обеих таблицах = целое. А то может случиться, что в одной таблице - целое, в другой - длинное целое. 2. Я бы рекомендовал первичный ключ сделать на поле [ID] типа `counter` , а связку [код отдела] + [название отдела] оформил как `constraint`. Это как минимум позволит избежать дублирования данных в двух таблицах. А лучше, КМК, и везде сделать так. Структура может измениться, а [ID] останется неизменным.

Comment: Не лишняя ли связь Отделы.НазваниеОтдела->ШтатноеРасписание.НазваниеОтдела? Да и само поле ШтатноеРасписание.НазваниеОтдела выглядит излишним. Если оно нужно "для истории" - связь не нужна.